# Sort active sheet when looping through files for copy/paste to single sheet

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, loops

I'm using the code below to try to loop through a lot of excel sheet in a folder. I want the code to open the file, sort it alphabetically, then do a custom sort, then copy paste everything to a new sheet. By itself, the sort works perfectly if I run it on a sheet I opened. Inside the loop below, though, nothing sorts, as it pastes unsorted values to the new sheet. To be clear, the loop through that puts everything into one sheet works, and the sort part works. It's just when putting them together that the sort stops happening. I think the problem is that my code is trying to sort ThisWorkbook instead of the sheet it just opened, though I'm not sure why. I'm incredibly new to VBA.

```
Sub MergeFiles()

Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("PATH")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj

Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("A1:ER1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:ER195")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("A1:ER1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:="thing1,thing2,thing3", _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:ER195")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Range("A2:ES" & Range("A196").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: a) Do you need Excel to guess whether there is a header or not? Could that be definitely `xlYes` or `xlNo` through the loop? b) Could you confirm that you want to sort `xlLeftToRight` and not `xlTopToBottom`? I only ask the latter as it is almost never used. c) is `A1:ER195` a static area or is there more or less depending upon the workbooks/worksheets? d) which worksheet in the workbooks are you using as the source? Sheet1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are relying on the state (and object) held by `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheeet`. While opening a workbook typically makes it the `ActiveWorkbook`, bouncing between `ThisWorkbook` and the one most recently opened is not the desired approach.

```
Sub MergeFiles()
    Dim bookList As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object

    On Error GoTo Fìn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("PATH")
    Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
    For Each everyObj In filesObj
        If CBool(InStr(1, filsobj, ".xl", vbTextCompare)) Then
            Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=everyObj, ReadOnly:=True)

            With bookList.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(195, 148)
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                            DataOption:=xlSortNormal, CustomOrder:="thing1,thing2,thing3"
                wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(195, 149) = _
                  .Resize(195, 149).Values
            End With

            debug.print bookList.Name
            bookList.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set bookList = Nothing
        End If
    Next everyObj
Fìn:
    Set mergeObj = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A list of the processed workbooks will be available from the VBE's *Immediate Window* (aka `Ctrl+G`).

Comment: Thank you Jeeped. Yes, I do need it to be LeftToRight, but the Header could be No. Yes, it is a static area that I'm pulling from, and I only ever need Sheet(1). Actually just looking at your suggestion and sorting bookList.Sheets(1) instead of ActiveSheet solved my problem.